# ffmpeg errors out with error code: -5

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

Trying to run ffmpeg via pydub and receive:

```
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: -5

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib/libavutil.55.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib/libavutil.55.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Running python 2.7.11 and OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guessing your on Xcode 8,,try doing this

```
export HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1
Brew uninstall ffmpeg

Re-install FFMPEG
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, what was going on?
I'm out of upvotes at the moment will upvote tomorrow when I can again

Comment: Autotools tests for whether a given symbol is defined are
reliably coming to incorrect conclusions on 10.11 with the 10.12 SDK
in Xcode 8. This overrides its decisions by forcing the right answer
in superenv using ac_cv_func_* environment variables and setting them to
"no" on 10.11,,of which brew gets confused until developer mode is enable and merges everything together